# ASP.NET Ajax File Upload, Access Denied

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asyncfileupload

I'm having some trouble using the ASP.NET AJAX File Uploader.

I always get either:

> Unhandled Exception: Access is Denied

or

> Unhandled Exception: The File Attached is Invalid

To give you some background i'm working on .NET 4.0 and using the Ajax toolkit dll

To get to this state all i have done is dragged a script manager onto the page, dragged the file upload onto the page and declared and linked a function to handle the upload success (save it etc..) I get the same errors with and without this function.

Answer (score 3):

You should check the target directory for access level. it seems, the reason for your problem might be about the "write access"

If you need an asp.net ajax upload sample project, check [this](http://pokein.codeplex.com/releases/view/54534?c)